# InvalidSelectorException while locating an element on Android app

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium, android-uiautomator

I am automating an android application with Appium. I am trying to locate an element using UIAutomatorviewer tool provided by Android SDK. Following is the xpath I have found, but I think it might be wrong:

```
"//android.widget.EditText[@index=0]//android.view.ViewGroup[@index=1]"+ "preceding-sibling::android.view.ViewGroup//android.widget.TextView"
```

Whenever I execute I get following error:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS). (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 39 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html

Please help. Attaching UIAutomatorviewer tool snapshot for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the xpath is incorrect. Working xpath would look like this.

```
"//android.widget.EditText[@index=0]//android.view.ViewGroup[@index=1]/preceding-sibling::android.view.ViewGroup//android.widget.TextView"
```

You were missing the / before the preceding-sibling, which causes the invalid selector exception.